# Ajax post request nested parameters no data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to make an Ajax request to my rails controller using Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/vulnerabilities/export',
  type: 'GET',
  processData: false,
  data: {export: {ids: this.refs.table.state.selectedRowKeys }}
});
```

When there is data for the ID's (which come from checkboxes) the parameters are correct and look like this

```
{"export"=>{"ids"=>["1", "2"]}, "controller"=>"export", "action"=>"index"}
```

However when there are no id's the params are like this

```
{"controller"=>"export", "action"=>"index"}
```

What I want is for it to send an empty array when there are no id's so it looks like this

```
{"export"=>{"ids"=>[]}, "controller"=>"export", "action"=>"index"}
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: When ajax call is made if only sends values if the values are not null!!!!
However it mite send undefined values!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the param is an array and then verify the length before setting it in the data section.

```
/**
* Gets some type of vulnerabilities
* @param Array
*/
function getExport(ids) {
    var idSet = (Array.isArray(ids) && ids.length > 0) ? ids : [];
    $.ajax({
      url: '/vulnerabilities/export',
      type: 'GET',
      processData: false,
      data: {export: {"ids": idSet }, ...}
    });

}
```